# Imbricated C++ template

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following pattern:

```
template <int a, int b>
class MyClass
{
public:
  template <int c>
  MyClass<a, c> operator*(MyClass<b, c> const &other) const;
};

// ../..

template <int a, int b> template <int c>
MyClass<a, c> MyClass<a, b>::operator*(MyClass<b, c> const &other) const //< error here
{
  MyClass<a, c> result;
  // ..do stuff..
  return result;
}
```

It doesn't compile, the error message is

> Error C2975. error C2975: 'dom' : invalid argument template for 'MyClass'

If I replace `template <int c>` by `template <int c, int d>` and use it accordignly, it works fine. But I want `d` to be the same value as `b`.

My questions:

1. Why the example doesn't work?
2. How can I enforce `d` to be the same than `b`?

Thanks.

Comment: Almost +1 for "imbricated". Is that a commonly used phrase in C++ templating?

Comment: Could you show the code that instantiates the template? It sounds like you might be trying to use a variable for a parameter (e.g. `int number = stuff(); MyClass<1,number> thing;`), when numerical template parameters must be compile-time constants.

Comment: @Thilo: I really don't know, is it wrong. @Mike: I totally agree, but the thing is I don't instanciate it yet.

Comment: Hmmm... A template taking 2 ints in its declaration and a multiplication function that returns an instance that takes the 1st template parameter from LHS and 2nd from RHS, I'll assume this is a matrix class then :P

Comment: It's hard to imagine how that error can come from this code, especially when avakar's identical code compiles. Are you sure you're not instantiating the template? What is `dom` (mentioned in the error message)? Are you absolutely sure the error comes from the line you've marked? What happens in `// ..do stuff..`?

Comment: By the way, this is usually called a "nested" template. But "imbricated" is a perfectly cromulent word.

Comment: Hum, in fact `MyClass` inherits from `QVector` which happens to have an internal private variable called `d` and in my test code `c` was called `d` too. I didn't thought that unreachable member variables could interfere with the template definition.

Comment: If this is indeed matrix, I would suggest using an unsigned integer to avoid `-1` passed as parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately there is whole difference between visibility and accessibility. Symbols are resolved according to the visibility (ie do they exist in this scope or any parent scope, with override rule etc...) and then the accessibility is checked...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code compiles fine for me (as it should).

```
template <int a, int b>
struct MyClass
{
    template <int c>
    MyClass<a, c> operator*(MyClass<c, b> const &other) const;
};

template <int a, int b> template <int c>
MyClass<a, c> MyClass<a, b>::operator*(MyClass<c, b> const &other) const
{
    MyClass<a, c> result;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass<1, 2> a;
    MyClass<3, 2> b;
    a * b;
}
```

Note that in your code:

1. You are returning a reference to a temporary.
2. The `operator *` is not accessible from outside the class because it's private.

Please post real code and indicate the line casing the error.

Comment: I made some edit to make the code more accurate. Thanks for the tip about the reference.
Your example compiles, mine still doesn't except if I define the body of the method inside the class (!).
BTW any reasons for using the `struct` keyword instead of `class`?

Comment: The default access mode of `struct` is `public`, thus it saves space in examples ;)

Comment: This code is now identical to yours, except for the `// ..do stuff..` part. Perhaps the error is there? (Using `struct` makes the member public, but apart from that is exactly the same as `class`).